# Have Ubuntu 9.10 desktop, just got Macbook Pro. Share over Samba, NFS, other?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, mac, network-share, ubuntu-9.10

As the title says, I have and love my Ubuntu 9.10 desktop (use it for programming). Just got a Macbook Pro (Snow Leopard) and stuff like Documents, etc, trying to figure out easiest way to share my Ubuntu desktop with my Macbook Pro.

Should I use Samba or NFS and is it easy to configure one (or something else) for only in network access (192.168.1.x).

It took me about 2 days to find/setup Macfuse and Macfusion for sshfs to the Fedora web server and I'm hoping there's something much easier for this in network access. But if it requires or is suggested I go ssh, I can do that.

Are there any security problems with either Samba or NFS - don't know much about AFP-Apple protocol so I've not brought it up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS with Keberos is very secure, but setting up Kerberos is quite a big deal and without Kerberos it can be very insecure.

Samba on Ubuntu is very easy to setup and pretty secure out of the box - see [this how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba#Ubuntu%20Server).
[Host based security](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/securing-samba.html#id2618304) should secure it to your LAN - see that page also for other security info.

Comment: Agree completely regarding NFS. Whatever none Kerberos NFS actually is a problem or not of course depends on what other computers there are on the internal network.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have Samba up and running, and you only want access to the files from your Mac, I'd recommend setting up [netatalk](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net) on your Ubuntu machine. [Google points to this tutorial.](http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/06/ubuntu-as-mac-file-server-and-time-machine-volume/)